# Check for resource existance in spring batch

Tags: dynamic, file-io, resources, spring-batch, filereader

In my spring batch application I am specifying the input file name dynamically. I want to check whether the file is available in particular path before going to read. If not found I have to notify it. The job should not get failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpringBatch - How to catch a Read Exception when resource doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257659/springbatch-how-to-catch-a-read-exception-when-resource-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 0):

1. If job is already started, you can use before step in item processor to check file existence and execute your job accordingly

   > ```
   > @BeforeStep
   > public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
   > // do your file operation here
   > }
   > ```
2. Before stating job, check the file and start job.
   edit
3. Add a job listener for job and in beforeJob or aftreJob method check if file exists before processing.

> ```
> <job id="testJob">
>   <listeners>
>       <listener ref="testJobListener"/>
>   </listeners>
>   <Step>Step configuration</Step>
> </Job>
> ```